# calculating Bergman kernel of punctured unit disk

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, complex-integration, bergman-spaces

Any idea how can we calculate the Bergman kernel of the punctured unit disk?
I know how to find the Bergman kernel of the unit disk, for example, we have complete orthonormal basis for the Bergman space $A^2(\mathbb{D})$.

Is it true that the complete orthonormal basis of $A^2(\mathbb{D}^{*})$ same as $A^2(\mathbb{D})$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I proved that the two spaces have the same complete orthonormal basis, $\sqrt{\dfrac{n+1}{\pi}}z^n$, $n=0,1,2, \cdots$. Thus both spaces have have the same kernel.

Comment: Shouldn't you accept your answer?